# CSS loading is incorrect

Tags: javascript, css

I have CSS embedded inside the page as `<style type="text/css">`  and I have CSS referred as using `<link href>`.

How to make sure that the CSS specified in `<link>` gets loaded first before the `<style type="text/css">`?

Right now, the css embedded inside the page gets precedence, causing some style issues.
in the below image, I need `.sanddbox dropdown-menu` to take precedence before `.dropdown-menu`. I can get this if I load the css files using `link` tag.
But I want them to be embedded in the page.

[image]

Comment: Put your tags in the order you want them to load?

Comment: The min.js (which has information on dynamic CSS injection) is loaded using require(".js"). And the css is inside html.

Comment: Might it make sense to look into the specificity of your CSS? It shouldn't matter what order your CSS loads.

Comment: I have the question updated with some technical terms. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: I haven't used require. Can you not tell it where to put the `link` tag? What's the issue that addressing the order will solve? Are you declaring a class in the `link` tag that you want to overwrite in the `style` tag using the same selector?

Comment: Your question does not make any reference to to the use of requirejs or r.js, nor indeed any JavaScript at all. Please edit your question to show how those are relevant, or remote the tags altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In line styles and style blocks in the page will always over ride any external css files.  The correct thing to do is remove the in line css.  I am assuming you can't do that for some resaon (there are many).  Then the only way to overcome that is to put `!important` after the attribute in the css file.

eg:

```
div.test {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: The external CSS file has many attributes. Should I need to include !important to every single attribute in the class?

Comment: No, there's almost never a need for the use of `!important`. Just make sure the selectors or more specific.

Comment: The selectors are more specific. For ex: the element has the class `sample dropdown`. In the external css I have `.sample dropdown`. there is a bootstrap `dropdown` style is embedded in the page. So, the attributes in `bootstrap dropdown`  takes precedence than `.sample dropdown`

Comment: you can see from the attached image. I need `.sandbox dropdown-menu` to take precedence before `.dropdown-menu`

Comment: `.sandbox-dropdown-menu` is not more specific than `.dropdown-menu`.  They are exactly the same level of specificity.  `div.sandbox-dropdown-menu` would be more spcecific. `.dropdown-menu.sandbox dropdown-menu` would be more specific if the element had both classes.  Read up on specificity here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I agree. adding specifity fixed the issue. I have the same class represented in div, button and ul. So, I need to add all possible combinations. Thanks for the answer.